# Hiding div in Android WebView app with java doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a div called `downloadapp` that I'd like to display to users who visit my mobile website instead of using my Android app. So I need to hide that div for users who already use my app.

**My code:**

```
private void startWebView(String url) {
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      

    //On error, open local file
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/myerrorpage.html");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              
        view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('downloadapp').style.display = 'none';");
    }   

});

webView.loadUrl(url);

}
```

**Problem:**

My app loads the div first and its actually being displayed for a couple of seconds. Then suddenly, the whole webpage loaded in the app disappears and a blank page with the word "none" is the only thing that is left on the screen.

Is there something wrong with the way I try to hide the div "downloadapp" or what am I missing here?

What I want it to do is immediately hide the div before the webpage is being displayed.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening on newer versions of WebView -- if your app is targeting API level 19 or above (KitKat), then if a `javascript:` URL returns a value, this value is interpreted as content for a new web page to open. In your case, as `'none'` is the return value of the assignment, it is used as the content for a new page.

Just put `void(0);` at the end of your code in `javascript:` to prevent it from returning a value.

Comment: Thanks, that works. However I still got the problem that the div is being displayed for a few seconds (until the page is loaded). Any idea how I could hide it immediately?

Comment: One possible way is to add some identifying string into your app's user agent string, e.g. like this: `webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString() + '; myapp')`, and then hide the div in your page's code: `if (navigator.userAgent.endsWith('myapp')) document.getElementById('downloadapp').style.display = 'none'`

Comment: I added this in my app: `webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString() + "; myapp");`
And this in my page's header:
`<script>
     if (navigator.userAgent.endsWith('myapp')) {
   document.getElementById('downloadapp').style.display = "none";
  } else { 
   document.getElementById('downloadapp').style.display = "inherit";
  }
 </script>`
But it doesn't work. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Hmm. Did you try to debug? See https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews